# how can I add images to my <a> dropdown menu buttons (animating both, the dropdown menu and the images)

Tags: html, error-handling, drop-down-menu, css-animations

I wanna make something like this and i've been trying to do it for days now, I'm struggling to place the image (dropdown arrow) next to my button, I want the dropdown arrow to be an image and I want it to smoothly rotate 180 degrees onclick.

(what I want to make)
https://www.veed.io/view/308a765c-bb6e-4cbb-9611-64e37acbb17e?sharingWidget=true&panel=share

What im getting:
https://www.veed.io/view/4135c468-5457-41ca-903d-e3ba934881d4?sharingWidget=true&panel=share

the white arrow is lower than I want it to be and it won't go up with padding or margin, the filled purple arrow isnt dynamic(changes locations depending on screensize) and I believe the dropdown menu is so low because of the image's padding (the image is the white, hollow arrow)